# How to use element DataObject with Apache Tuscany?

Tags: apache, createelement, apache-tuscany

I have a an XSD schema which contains both xsd types and elements of that types.

Like this:

```
TargetNamespace: http://mycorp.com/ws
Type: PaymentType
Element: PaymentElement
```

I need to create a commonj.sdo.DataObject representing the PaymentElement.
All I can do with the Tuscany API is create commonj.sdo.DataObject of type PaymentType, which is not suitable.

I created it like so:

```
DataFactory factory = scope.getDataFactory();
DataObject req = factory.create("http://mycorp.com/ws", "PaymentType");
```

How can I create commonj.sdo.DataObject elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.
The trick was to create a subtype of element's type with name same as the element's name.

More info in my question in CXF mailing list. [link](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Using-SDOs-commonj-sdo-DataObject-with-CXF-td5714321.html#a5714415)

The solution is not so clean but allows a correct serialization etc.